# Replace English script with another script in Microsoft Word

Tags: microsoft-word

I have a Microsoft Word document where a text is written in English letters. I simply want to change them to display as Georgian letters. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect you need to select the text and change to a different font.

This could be done best, probably, with a character style that might also carry a language attribute for Georgian.

Comment: Changing to a "Georgian only" font did work but I wish there was a way to simply change the letter's Unicode number since Georgian is included in Unicode and I really like how the characters look in Sylfaen. Thanks for the response

Comment: I'm not sure what is simple about changing a letter's Unicode number. A character style seems like the best option. It can be attached to a simple keyboard shortcut. https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word-mso_win10-msoversion_other/assigning-keyboard-shortcuts-in-microsoft-word/a346f277-e0eb-4d17-b53b-233584c611bb?tm=1595883735330